# How to ban ban ctrl+c in erlang

Tags: erlang

I use run_erl to start an erlang application, just like this

```
run_erl -daemon /tmp/erl_pipe /tmp/erl_log "erl -name 1@127.0.0.1 -setcookie 123456"
```

Then I Attach to erlang shell like this

```
to_erl /tmp/erl_pipe
```

And the question is, I used to quit erlang shell with 'ctrl + c', in this situation, 'ctrl+c' will quit the main node, I have seen my lead to ban this command by modify erlang/OTP source code, how to do that?

Answer (score 5):

Start Erlang as `erl +Bi`. Note that you'll have to use `init:stop()` (shortcut `q()` in the shell) or `halt()` to stop the node if signals are ignored. Also, the Ctrl-G menu will not have the q option if you use this flag.

It is also possible to use `+Bc`, which makes Ctrl-C abort the current shell command instead of stopping the whole node. In this case, you can still use q from the Ctrl-G menu.

See http://erlang.org/doc/man/erl.html#emu_flags for the full documentation on runtime system flags.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this is not what I want. I do not want to start erl as 'erl +Bi' or 'erl + Bc', cuz I need to run the application in background so I can see the erlang shell output in log. Anyway, Thanks.

Comment: You should combine the +B flag with your other erl flags (-name and -setcookie above) in the run_erl command. This will avoid killing the node accidentally with Ctrl-C when you have attached with to_erl.

Comment: Note that using to_erl, you should press Ctrl-D to disconnect. The +B flag is only to ensure that you don't press the wrong key by mistake and bring down the node.